# Recursive method in the Java merge sort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the below merge sort code in my application. I am very confused on how the recursive method gets called again after it comes out of the if block when the if condition is not met.

I debugged my code, but I am still not getting it. The sort method that calls mergesort(0, number - 1) starts first at mergesort(0, 5). low is less than high, middle is 2, so mergesort(0, 2) is run next. This goes on until we have mergesort(0, 0) in which case low is not less than high, 
so it comes out of the if block. But when I debug, the method returns, and it starts again after mergesort(0, 0) case. How does the call happen again?

```
    public class MergeSort {
        private int[] numbers;
        private int[] helper;

    private int number;


    public int[] sort(int[] values) {
        this.numbers = values;
        number = values.length;
        this.helper = new int[number];
        return mergesort(0, number - 1);
    }

    private int[] mergesort(int low, int high) {
        // check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
        if (low < high) {
            // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
            int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
            // Sort the left side of the array
            mergesort(low, middle);
            // Sort the right side of the array
            mergesort(middle + 1, high);
            // Combine them both
            merge(low, middle, high);
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    private int[] merge(int low, int middle, int high) {

        // Copy both parts into the helper array
        for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            helper[i] = numbers[i];
        }

        int i = low;
        int j = middle + 1;
        int k = low;
        // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
        // to the original array
        while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
            if (helper[i] <= helper[j]) {
                numbers[k] = helper[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                numbers[k] = helper[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
        while (i <= middle) {
            numbers[k] = helper[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        return numbers;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `mergesort` method calls itself twice. You can print out the stack to see what happens.

For example, when call `mergesort(0,1)`, the method will call `mergesort(0,0)` first and then `mergesort(1,1)`.

Comment: correct; its easier to understand when you write down the method call on top of the previous one on paper and see where you are; or using java stack trace.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried, but I couldn't figure it out. Thank you so much locoyou.